# Find Element by Dictionary-ID in Python List[Dict]

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem I got, is the following: I got JSON-Data which I already converted to a dictionary. The JSON-Data looks like this:

```
[{"text": "foo1", "value": 1},
{"text": "foo2", "value": 2}]
```

So my converted json in Python is
`json = [{'text': 'foo1', 'value': 1}, {'text': 'foo2', 'value': 2}]`.

The *text* in these dictionaries is random data and can be swapped for anything the *value* on the other hand can be interpreted as a fix and unique ID from 1 to infinity.

Now my question is what would possible be the most efficient way of getting out the *text*.

Because what I tried was

```
foo1 = [v['text'] for v in json if json['value'] == 1][0]    # and
foo2 = {list(v.values())[1]: list(v.values())[0] for v in json}[2]
```

though I have to admit that I am not really happy with these solutions...

Comment: Number 1 should be replaced by a usual for-loop which you can "break" when the unique id was found. It is then the most efficient way if you only need a few of the "text" entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way, if you need to get **several** items by `value`, is to convert this list of dicts into a dict with `value` as keys and `text` as values:

```
d = { x['value']: x['text'] for x in dic }
```

Now you can just use `d[n]` to find `text` for `value` equal `n`.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend Błotosmętek's answer if you need to do multiple lookups, however if you just need a single value, I would recommend:

```
def lookup(value):
    return next(v['text'] for v in json if v['value'] == value)
```

This is similar to the code you gave, but the big difference is that it does not have to search the entire list even after it has found the value, because it uses a generator rather than list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for sharing both answers. Because of my usecase I think I will go with Błotosmętek answer though.

Comment: Ok, I fully accept that my answer is worse for many use cases!